# Glide with Fragment Context

Tags: android, android-context, android-glide

This is related to [Glide image loading with application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964737/glide-image-loading-with-application-context/32887693#32887693)

I have several Fragments hosted in an Activity, with a Fragment being replaced by another as the user navigates through the app.

I'm passing a `RequestManager` into my MyFragment's RecyclerView adapter like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(Glide.with(this), listOfPhotos);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private RequestManager mGlide;

    ...

    // constructor
    public MyAdapter(RequestManager glide, List<MyStuff> listOfPhotos) {
        mGlide = glide;

        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

When I debug my app, here's what I see in the object mGlide:

[image: Debug information in mGlide object]

The `context` seems to be my project's `ApplicationContext`. Now I'm not very familiar with Android contexts, but is this right? I assumed it will be something like com.MyFragment.....

Also, is there a simple way to check if glide is following my fragments' lifecycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This question would've been better suited for [Glide's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/glidelibrary) linked from the [Readme](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#getting-help).*

Your usage looks clean and performant, and that's the way I suggest to go with.

> The context seems to be my project's ApplicationContext.

`Glide` is a singleton, and hence it wouldn't make any sense to initialize it with the first `Activity` it sees (see `Glide.get`). If you check how `RequestManager` actually uses that `Context` you'll see it is passed all around the place, which again wouldn't be useful and would leak. It is mostly used for `.getContentResolver` and to acquire the `Glide` singleton via `Glide.get(context)` in those other classes.

> I assumed it will be something like com.MyFragment...

What you're looking for can be found in the following fields of `RequestManager`:

```
private final Lifecycle lifecycle;
private final RequestManagerTreeNode treeNode;
private final RequestTracker requestTracker;
```

See all child classes / implementations of those types. Also check the `Context.mActivityLifecycleCallbacks` I think those are the same objects.

> Is there a simple way to check if glide is following my fragments' lifecycles?

You can put breakpoints in the above mentioned classes, and/or check if the resources are freed via a heap dump (this last one may be tricky because of caching). If you want more insight you can try enabling logging as said on the Wiki: [Debugging and Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling) and also write your own loggers for listener/target, like I did in [glide-support/...utils](https://github.com/TWiStErRob/glide-support/tree/master/src/glide3/java/com/bumptech/glide/supportapp/utils).