# Android Glide Context Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-glide

My question goes thus:

> Does Glide create different caches for each object i.e Context, Fragment
>   cause when i used `glide` to load images into my adapter, on another activity the image is then redownloaded again. And i don't wan't that.

I load the images in the fragment with:

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load("<url>").thumbnail(0.1f).crossfade().into(imageView);
```

And in the opened activity :

```
Glide.with(this).load("<url>").thumbnail(0.1f).crossfade().into(imageView);
```

then the image is re-downloaded which consumes more data.

and when i use application context --> the app crashes.

What can i do to fix this behavior?.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964737/glide-image-loading-with-application-context

Comment: I would prefer to use the app context but it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Glide doesn't maintain separate caches per `Activity` or `Fragment`.

The reason you're getting a cache miss is probably because the `View` you're using in your `Fragment` doesn't have exactly the same width and height as the `View` you're using in your `Activity`.

You can either use [`DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/DiskCacheStrategy.html#SOURCE) (only makes sense for remote images), or you can use a fixed size using [`override()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#override(int,%20int)) in both places.