# Glide - App crashes with a context error in another activity

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-context, android-glide

I have a problem with `Glide`. This problem happens in this way:

I go to my profile page, then I click back button, then I insert an object in my Firebase database (Now the app crashes). The problem is in my `UserProfile` activity but I don't know how to resolve this. I have read two similar posts but I don't understand well. ([Glide error after activity was destroyed and restarted](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1032) and [Glide image loading with application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964737/glide-image-loading-with-application-context/32887693#32887693))

My `logcat` is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
                                                                           at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:134)
                                                                           at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:102)
                                                                           at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
                                                                           at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
                                                                           at gamingproject.sellmybooks.UserProfile.getUserData(UserProfile.java:114)
                                                                           at gamingproject.sellmybooks.UserProfile.access$000(UserProfile.java:39)
                                                                           at gamingproject.sellmybooks.UserProfile$1.onDataChange(UserProfile.java:75)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaie.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.zzcta(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5608)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
```

Profile class:

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

Context mContext;
ImageView userProfileImage;
TextView name, mail, user_location_textView;
String tag_login;
String user_name, user_mail, user_token, user_urlPicture, user_location, user_key;
String TAG_LOGIN = "TAG_LOGIN";
String KEY = "KEY";
int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE;
DatabaseReference users;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_user_profile);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    mContext = this;

    userProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mail);
    user_location_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_location);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tag_login = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_LOGIN);
    user_key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);

    users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("User" + tag_login).child(user_key);

    users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getUserData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}


///Get user's data with the key///

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void getUserData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
     if (Objects.equals(tag_login, "App")){
        UserApp userApp = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserApp.class);
        user_name = userApp.user_name;
        user_mail = userApp.user_mail;
        user_token = userApp.user_token;
        user_location = userApp.user_location;
        user_urlPicture = userApp.user_bitmapImage;
        name.setText(user_name);
        mail.setText(user_mail);
        user_location_textView.setText(user_location);
        if (Objects.equals(user_urlPicture, "NoImage")){
            userProfileImage.setImageResource(drawable.noimage);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click on image to change it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user_urlPicture).into(userProfileImage);
        }
        userProfileImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Please post out the code.

Comment: Post you userProfile class

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: `UserProfile.java:114` What line 114?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove the value change listener during your activity onDestroy.

Something like this:

```
// during onCreate(Bundle)
users.addValueEventListener(listener);

// then during onDestroy()
users.removeValueEventListener(listener);

// outside any method you write the listener
private ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getUserData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Budius

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your listener got called when the user already navigated away from the activity. You need to remove the listener when the activity is destroyed. Or at least check if those views are null before setting texts.