# You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

MainActivity has below code for load GIF, the application gets a crash for load GIF after restart activity.

```
 ImageView imageViewGIF = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGIF);
    Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.drawable.gift_3).into(imageViewGIF);
```

Loading GIF in ImageView using glide

But when I restart the app due to some requirement using

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Application get a crash with below log.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.apppackage, PID: 19360
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
     at android_support.qc.b(RequestManagerRetriever.java:298)
     at android_support.qc.a(RequestManagerRetriever.java:123)
     at android_support.ji.a(Glide.java:589)
```

I have used `'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'`

Comment: Where are you using/loading  Glide? Inside fragments, Activity or Customer View?

Comment: @AshishTiwari inside the activity in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue in Glide library. You can check the context for not equals to null before loading Glide or you can use application context for this.

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
  .load(imageUrlToLoad)
  .into(ImageView);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the application context, here is why https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887693/1390881

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps somebody, but for me was a struggle. I've used `Glide.with(getApplicationContext())` but it didn't work.

So, I had to do an if condition to check if activity is Destroyed something like this:

```
  if (!isDestroyed) {
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) 
    ....
  }
```

This worked perfectly for me! Hope will be helpful for somebody