# Glide issues on openning. Can't load

Tags: android

I am having some error in my activity adapter using glide and also when I use on fragment.
I am trying to load a video thumbnail when users send videos to each other.

Here is my code:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.isMemoryCacheable();
Glide.with(activity)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
        .load(dialogList.get(position).getVideoUrl()) // or URI/path
        .into(viewHolder.Right_videoview);
```

**logcat:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:323)
   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:132)
   at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:732)
   at chat.espana.esp.adapter.ChatListAdapter.getView(ChatListAdapter.java:391)
   at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:232)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2511)
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:820)
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1793)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2304)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19682)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6086)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
```

I appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(...)
```

Instead of:

```
Glide.with(TabMorePagesDetailActivity.this).load(...)
```

This will stop it from crashing, but will still use the resources to load the image even if the activity has been destroyed. –

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887693/5595926](http://Link)

Comment: I have added and this is not work. Thank